# Domain Authority during domain migration

Tags: seo, domains

I have a site that I want to migrate from one domain to another, the domain I want to migrate my site to currently has an existing site of mine on it.

For the sake of this question let's call the current domain `example1.com`, and the migration domain `example2.com`.

Weighing up the risks involved in the migration, I have found that the `example1.com` has a domain authority of 30 while `example2.com` has an authority of 15. I have got these metrics from Moz's MozBar tool.

So my questions are:

On migrating these domains, is this likely to cause a drop in rankings?

If I point both domains at the same site, with `example2.com` being the primary domain, will the authority from `example1.com` be passed on to `example2.com` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will definitely be some link juice pushed over from the DA 30 domain to the DA 15 domain. But how much juice gets passed over depends on how relevant `example1.com` is to `example2.com`.

For example, if `example1.com` is a site to buy vinyl albums and `example2.com` is a site about cooking spices, then you aren't going to get much of a ranking boost from it. But if `example2.com` was a site about music, specifically selling vinyl music, then you would have a much better chance at a ranking boost.

Comment: Both sites are relevant to each other. So when Google crawls the new setup, will the transfer of juice happen straight after this crawl, or is likely to remain at 15 at first before it increases, therefore causing a hit in rankings?

Comment: It won't happen straight after the crawl, I'd give it a few weeks. SEO isn't an overnight task.

Comment: In fact, it could take a month or two. But you should be okay in the end. Just make sure that you are not breaking inbound links (if possible) since that is likely the bulk of the domains value. If you can overlay the two with the exception of obvious collisions such as the home page (for example), the better off you will be.

Answer (score 1):

If you migrate the two domain names like `example1.com` to `example2.com` there is a little bit of rank is going down because the redirection is the one of the factor in Google SEO 200 factors so,

Do the better SEO for `example2.com` website and maintain the proper *.htaccess* redirection to your sites and maintain the Good content and Proper SEO. Your site will grow up automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There will definitely be some link juice pushed over from the DA 30 domain to the DA 15 domain. But how juice gets passed over depends on how relevant example1.com is to example2.com.

For example, if example1.com is a site to buy vinyl albums and example2.com is a site about cooking spices, then you aren't going to get much of a ranking boost from it. But if example2.com was a site about music, specifically selling vinyl music, then you would have a much better chance at a ranking boost.

Comment: This post does appear to answer the question, so I have not deleted it even though it did contain a promotional link.  It is not appropriate to answer questions here for the primary purpose of including a link that you wish to promote.

Comment: I'm sorry u can remove it

Comment: Sure -- I already edited the post to remove the link.